# TinyMCE plugin jbimages (JustBoil.me) not uploading image after server update

Tags: php, tinymce, tinymce-4, justboil.me

After updating our server to PHP 5.6 and installing TinyMCE 4 with [jbimages plugin](http://justboil.me/) I have issues with uploading images to server.

The plugin is visible in TinyMCE, dialog window opens, but when I select image to be uploaded to server in file browser, it does not get uploaded, it just says it is taking longer than usual. I am using this same setup on many projects and haven't had this issue before...

What I tried and found out:

Plugin is trying to send a POST request to server:

**POST http://{my_domain}/auth/data/tiny_mce-4.3.4/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php?upload/english**

But the server sends back empty response.

Chrome console says "net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE", Firefox says "The connection was reset"...

The script itself seems to be accessible (curl to http://{my_domain}/auth/data/tiny_mce-4.3.4/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php?upload/english sends back HTML response, saying in it "Result:  You did not select a file to upload.", which is correct)

The request in the plugin comes from file [dialog-v4.htm:17](https://github.com/vikdiesel/justboil.me/blob/master/dialog-v4.htm):

```
<input id="uploader" name="userfile" type="file" class="jbFileBox" onChange="document.upl.submit(); jbImagesDialog.inProgress();">
```

Has anyone dealt with this problem too? I really need to get this working... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just got some info from a server admin. It seems like this plugin is making some Apache PHP module crash... After trying to upload image, there is one or more lines added to a server log:


**"[Thu Mar 03 09:38:39.210424 2016] [core:notice] [pid 46333] AH00052: child pid 92894 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)"**

Looks like we will not use this plugin anymore...

Comment: Have u been able to solve it ? I am facing the same problem with an infinite upload without it really uploading

Comment: If I remember correctly, with this particular Server configuration we just gave up and used a different plugin. The jbimages doesn't seem to be maintained anymore in last 2 years. It was simple to use, but when I looked into it's code... Well you can imagine it was kinda hacky :) We went with [El Finder](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder) in the end, but there are other good plugins you can discuss in the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I have recently found Open Manager
  
http://www.designsandcode.com/261/open-manager-tinymce-file-manager/

and it works perfectly, far more easier to use than jbimages.